# How can I restrict access to a widget to admins only?

Tags: php

I have a very basic text widget, all it does is link to a PHP script which displays a random banner image. I would like to restrict viewing access to admins whilst I'm testing the widget. How is this possible? Can I use a WP function to restrict access to this widget?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following on top of your code:

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) );
    return;
```

Comment: All it does is stop the randomiser script working, which makes the image link broken. I've tried that before. I'd like to be able to hide the entire widget.

Comment: "All it does is": aborts if the current user doesn't have the capability of `manage_options` which is assigned to admins per default. If your link (wherever this comes from - you showed no code) is broken, then you should place the above code somewhere else: exactly where you need to abort.

Comment: I need to stop the widget from being displayed

Comment: To make this _clear_: I can't **guess** what your exact code is. I showed you the possibilty to _abort_ if a requirement wasn't met. Where you place this is now up to _you_. "I need to stop the widget from being displayed" sadly is no help. Post your code/Update your Q or try/error until it works.